# Kotlin ListView IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: kotlin, listview

(new to kotlin) I'm making my own music app but i'm having an error that i don't understand :

- in the bit of code where i try to access a random view (shuffle), i get the java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:96 Size:11.
- 96 in this example is the view in the listview that i'm trying to access.
- It happens in this line : `var iView = listViewMusic.get(idShuffle)`
- Same if i use `listViewMusic[idShuffle]`

EDIT : Turns out that 11 is only the 11 visible items on screen at any given moment, even if the list contains hundreds of items. When i use `listViewMusic.smoothscrolltoposition(idShuffle)` it works, but the size of 11 now relates to the 11 on screen after the scrolling

The function playNext() inside the activity, called when clicking on the shuffle button:

```
fun playNext(){

        try {
            // Find the order of the next song to play
            var idShuffle = musicAdapter!!.getIdofItem(listMusicShuffled.get(musicNextToPlay).title)

            // Find the right record in the list
            //var iView = listViewMusic[idShuffle]
            //toastIt(applicationContext, "adapter count ${listViewMusic.adapter.count}")
            //toastIt(applicationContext, "listview count ${listViewMusic.count}")
            var iView = listViewMusic.get(idShuffle) //throws the error

            // Play it
            playOrPause(iView)

            // Prepare the next track
            musicNextToPlay += 1
            if (musicNextToPlay >= listMusicShuffled.size) {
                musicNextToPlay = -1
            }
        } catch (e:Exception) {toastException(applicationContext, "playnext", e) }

    }
```

The part of the function onCreate that fills in the listViewMusic:

```
// Retrieve the data
val mediaStoreUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
val cursor = contentResolver.query(mediaStoreUri, null, "", null, null)

//Browse the data
listMusic = mutableListOf()
val listMusicJson = getMusicFromJson()
while (cursor!!.moveToNext()) {
      val musicName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
      val musicArtist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
      val musicUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
      val musicType:String =
                if (musicArtist.contains("lmdmf", true)) { "LMDMF" }
                else if (musicName.contains("slack", true)) { "SLACK" }
                else { "MUSIC" }

      listMusic.add(
               MusicTrack(
                         musicName,
                         musicPlayCount,
                         musicUrl,
                         musicType
                )
       )
}
cursor.close()

musicAdapter = MusicAdapter(listMusic.sortedWith(compareBy<MusicTrack>{ it.title }).filter { it.type == "MUSIC"}.toMutableList())
listViewMusic.adapter = musicAdapter
```

Comment: the error shows clearly that the size is `11`. You say that `listview.count` is `500`, but are trying to access `listViewMusic`. Are they the same object?

Comment: @Zulu you'll need to provide the code, we can't tell you where 11 comes from without seeing the code.

Comment: @Alex.T it is indeed the same listview (named listViewMusic), i edited my text to remove any doubt

Comment: @Shawn i added the bits of code that relate to the listview